# Type Castle.Facilities.FactorySupport.FactorySupportFacility does not implement the interface Castle.MicroKernel.IFacility

Tags: castle-windsor

I've updated my solution from castle version 1.0 to version 3.0 and now I get this error :

> Type Castle.Facilities.FactorySupport.FactorySupportFacility does not
>   implement the interface Castle.MicroKernel.IFacility.

in my config files I have this:

```
  <facilities>
    <facility
     id="factory.support"     
     type="Castle.Facilities.FactorySupport.FactorySupportFacility, Castle.MicroKernel"
    />
  </facilities>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assembly is wrong. This works.

```
  <facilities>
    <facility
     id="factory.support"     
     type="Castle.Facilities.FactorySupport.FactorySupportFacility, Castle.Windsor"
    />
  </facilities>
```

Comment: actually I saw this was moved into another assembly, and I got it via nuget, and used it instead of Castle.MicroKernel, is that right (cuz I have other errors now and I'm not sure if that was the fix)

Answer (score 1):

As of v3 of Castle the FactorySupportFacility exists in its own assembly outside Castle.Windsor. So to configure it you can use

```
<facility
 id="factory.support"     
 type="Castle.Facilities.FactorySupport.FactorySupportFacility, Castle.Facilities.FactorySupport"
/>
```